# I can't assign black background to my views

Tags: ios, ipad

I can't assign black background to either the rows of my table or the added ImageViews. (Each row has multiple imageViews. The backgrounds are always white. This is my code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [self wordAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 0.0 alpha: 1.0];

//NSString *url = self.imageURL;
//dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();

dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Flickr downloader in Photo", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSData *image = [FlickrFetcher imageDataFromPhotoId:@"2654899252"];
    NSData *image2 = [FlickrFetcher imageDataFromPhotoId:@"2654072649"];
    NSData *image3 = [FlickrFetcher imageDataFromPhotoId:@"2654072293"];        /*dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
        processImage(imageData);
    });*/

    UIImageView *imageView = nil;

    if(image) imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: image]];

    UIImageView *imageView2 = nil;
    if(image2) imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: image2]];

    UIImageView *imageView3 = nil;
    if(image3) imageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: image3]];

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 220, 200);
    imageView2.frame = CGRectMake(240.0, 0.0, 220, 200);
    imageView3.frame = CGRectMake(480.0, 0.0, 220, 200);

    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 0.0 alpha: 1.0];
    imageView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 0.0 alpha: 1.0];
    imageView3.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 0.0 alpha: 1.0];



    [cell addSubview:imageView];
    [cell addSubview:imageView2];
    [cell addSubview:imageView3];

    [imageView release];
    [imageView2 release];
    [imageView3 release];
});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

Comment: Maybe the images have white background?

Comment: @Jan Gressmann No the images have no border, and as you can see in the code they are located at 20 points of distance.

Comment: okay try adding: cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor black]; and cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor black];

Comment: @Jan Gressmann By the way it says method "+black" not found, I try now with RGB values.

Comment: Ok finally cell.contentView did the job. You know how can I remove also the borders of the cell (the horizontal lines separating each row) ?

Comment: oh sorry its [UIColor blackColor], lines are removed by setting tableView.separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone

Comment: @Jan Gressmann Sorry, one last thing: where can I set this property ? I guess I need to implement one of the superclass method. I only have methods invoked at row level. By the way, if you post your comments as answer I can vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay try adding:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Lines are removed by setting tableView.separatorStyle to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`

You should have a `UITableView` in your ViewController. If you're using a `UITableViewController` set the property in your viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}
```